# How do you calculate the difference between two timestamps in javascript, exluding weekends and nights?

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, momentjs

I am currently trying to figure out the best way to determine the length of time (in seconds or more precise) between two timestamps, while excluding weekends and off hours.

Weekends are the easier to handle and I've been able to do it just using if statements using ISO days/weeks with moment.js, but determining when to remove nights outside of set work hours (8-5) has proven to be rather difficult. Even if the initial or final timestamp happened to be in an off hour or weekend I still want all work hours counted.

I'll be running this on Google bigquery in a UDF with potentially millions of rows of data, so it also needs to be somewhat efficient. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide sample data ? So I can try to create a proper script for you. Also, is it a requirement to be done in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using BQ only, consider the following snippet in BigQuery StandardSQL:

```
with data as (
  select 1 as id, current_timestamp() as ts1, timestamp_add(current_timestamp(), interval 1 day) as ts2 union all
  select 2 as id, current_timestamp() as ts1, timestamp_add(current_timestamp(), interval 2 day) as ts2 union all
  select 3 as id, current_timestamp() as ts1, timestamp_add(current_timestamp(), interval 3 day) as ts2 union all
  select 4 as id, current_timestamp() as ts1, timestamp_add(current_timestamp(), interval 4 day) as ts2 union all
  select 5 as id, current_timestamp() as ts1, timestamp_add(current_timestamp(), interval 5 day) as ts2 union all
  select 6 as id, current_timestamp() as ts1, timestamp_add(current_timestamp(), interval 6 day) as ts2 union all
  select 7 as id, current_timestamp() as ts1, timestamp_add(current_timestamp(), interval 7 day) as ts2
),
temp as (
  select * 
  from data, unnest(generate_timestamp_array(timestamp_trunc(ts1,day),timestamp_trunc(ts2,day),interval 1 day)) calendar
)
select
  id, ts1, ts2,
  sum(
      case 
           -- Get # of Seconds on First Day from ts1 to 5:00PM
           when timestamp_trunc(ts1,day) = timestamp_trunc(calendar,day)
           then greatest(timestamp_diff(timestamp_add(calendar,interval 17 hour),ts1,second),0)
           -- Get # of Seconds on Last Day from 8:00AM to ts2
           when timestamp_trunc(ts2,day) = timestamp_trunc(calendar,day)
           then greatest(timestamp_diff(ts2,timestamp_add(calendar, interval 8 hour),second),0)
           -- Otherwise it is a full 8 hour day
           else 8*60*60
      end
     ) as working_seconds
from temp
where extract(dayofweek from calendar) not in (7,1) -- Exclude Saturday and Sunday
group by 1,2,3
```